# How to shrink the size of a row in a tableview after a label in that cell is hidden?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have used UITableViewAutomaticDimension but I want the tableview not to show the space where the label is hidden.

Comment: if you have autoresizing cells just change its height not hide

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` then you should make height of label `0` instead of hiding it so it will automatically change cell's height.

Now for make label's height `0` when you are using `autolayout`, you need to set `outlet` of your height constraint of your label.

Then set `constant` of that `heightConstraintOutlet` to `zero` instead of hiding and set it with desired value instead of `showing` it!!